# Do we only speak of a cut-vertex when talking about a connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I am new to graph theory and I am asked to prove this proposition in a homework assignment:

> Prove that a cut-vertex in a simple undirected graph is not a cut-vertex of its complement graph.

A **cut-vertex** is defined as one vertex whose removal results in a disconnected graph. My question is: When we talk about a cut-vertex, do we assume the graph is connected in the first place? In other words, is the notion of a cut-vertex defined for disconnected graphs?

Take the proposition above for example. A graph and its complement may not be simultaneously connected. Let $G$ be a graph with three vertices $u,v,w$. Let us connect $uv$ and $vw$. Then its complement has $u,v,w$ as vertices and only one edge $uw$, and is not connected. And in this case it may not make sense to say "prove something is not a cut-vertex" when you don't know the graph is connected or not.

Can someone clarify this for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In general,** definitions are not set in stone. When we define "cut vertex", we are thinking of connected graphs, and usually don't have to make a decision about what to do with disconnected ones. If you run into an application where it matters, you should make a decision that generalizes the usual one. I think there are two things that obviously make sense as generalizations:

- $v$ is a cut vertex of $G$ if $G-v$ is disconnected (whether that's because $G$ was already disconnected, or because deleting $v$ disconnected it).
- $v$ is a cut vertex of $G$ if it is a cut vertex of one of the connected components of $G$ (that is, if $G-v$ has more connected components than $G$).

But there could be other cases I'm not thinking of. Anyway, as long as you say what you mean, you can pick any option you like.

**In this specific problem,** there's only one unusual edge case. For an example of it, let $G$ consist of two $n$-cliques and a single vertex $v$ adjacent to every vertex in both cliques. (Then $v$ is a cut vertex of $G$.) In the complement, we have a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ and an isolated vertex $v$. For the problem to be valid, we don't want to consider $v$ to be a cut vertex in such a case, and I can't think of how you would.

Comment: Thanks. This explanation indeed makes more sense than what I had in mind, and is consistent with the proposition that I am trying to prove.

Answer (score 2):

A graph and its complement can both be connected.

Take for example $4$ vertices, the vertex set $V : \{ a, b, c, d\}$ and the edge set $ E: \{ ac, bc, bd\}$. Both the graph and its complement are connected.

Also, $c$ is a cut vertex in this graph but not in its complement.

[A cut vertex is any vertex whose removal increases the number of connected components.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component). So yes, $G$ could be disconnected, but we can talk about its cut vertex

Comment: Do you mean that if we say $v$ is (or is not) a cut-vertex of $G$, we take by default that $G$ is connected?

Comment: @trisct I think $G$ may be disconnected but the number of connected components of G must increase after removing all the edges containing that cut vertex

Comment: @trisct I think the definition I linked to might help